# NavbarBrand and the NavLink are not on the same level in reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, navbar

This is my react app and the code given below is the AppNavbar.js which is in my components folder:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './AppNavbar.css'
// import './AppNabar.css'
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
    Container
} from 'reactstrap';

class AppNavbar extends Component{
    state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div id='menu'>
            <Navbar color='dark' dark expand="sm" className='mb-5'>
                <Container className='allelements'>
                    <NavbarBrand href='/'>cloudBook</NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className='me-auto' navbar>
                        </Nav>
                            <NavLink href='https://github.com/Sarthak8822' className='gitlink'>Github</NavLink>
                    </Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default AppNavbar;
```

And this my App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar'

function App() {
  return (
    <AppNavbar />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Now the problem is that my Navbar elements are not aligned properly

[image]

I'm not able to get what the problem is in my AppNavbar.js file?
Please provide the Css styling or something which can resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked and kept mobile looking correct when it collapsed.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar-nav {
      margin-top: -3em;
   }
}
```

Maybe that or something similar will work for you.